# angular/cli@16 + primeng@16 : columns not aligned

Tags: angular, primeng

Please inspect the following angular application:
It contains an angular16 application with primeng16
app.component.html contains a very simple controls in 2 lines and 4 columns which should be aligned:

```css
.col1 {
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.col2 {
  width: 80px;
}

.col3 {
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.col4 {
  width: 80px;
  //align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-grid p-dir-col">
  <br />
  <div class="p-grid p-align-center p-nogutter">
    <label class="col1">First Pulse:</label>
    <input class="col2" type="text" pInputText />
    <label class="col3">Sampling Start:</label>
    <input class="col4" type="text" pInputText />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="p-grid p-align-center p-nogutter">
    <label class="col1">Last Pulse Delay:</label>
    <input class="col2" type="text" pInputText />
    <label class="col3">Sampling Length:</label>
    <input class="col4" type="text" pInputText />
  </div>
</div>
```

But the alignment is not working .
This code worked great in angular/cli@8.3.8 + primeng8

Can you please advise ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: stackoverflow's snippet does not included the css classes from primeNg in it, it will format the div the same way as without any css classes...

you will need to create a minimum reproducible problem with something like [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to make sure all the framework css is loaded correctly

Comment: I just rolled back your latest change on this question as it changed what was being asked...I advise you to create a new question when that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

[PrimeNg's flexGrid](https://primeflex.org/) changed a fair bit since version 8...

As [per docs](https://primeflex.org/gridsystem) when using it you no longer specify `col1`, `col2`... classes, but a as many `col` classes as needed:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col">
      // contents here
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      // contents here
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

And you can size the columns with a standard suffix when needed (1 to 12): `col-1`, `col-2` (which means, in order, 1 col with, 2 cols width)

When you need the columns to have a fixed width:

```
<div class="col-fixed" style="width:100px">
   ...
</div>
```

Have a look on the examples in the docs for more detail information

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I modified my question. Now I'm using a code sample from primeflex (and also installed primeflex 3.3.1). But I got a column. not a line.

Comment: you likely need to include references to the css files from primeflex. you need or to include `/node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css` in your angular style configurations or to add a reference to its [CDN link](https://primeflex.org/installation#loadfromcdn)

Comment: Hi. I added '/node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css' to the styles section in angular.json. But it did not work. Only after adding the CDN link to index.html it worked.  I can't use CDN link because I have to work in offline envornment, without internet.

Comment: Because the cdn ref woks, it means that the local ref was incorrect... did you restart the build once you modified the json file?

Comment: Hi. I restarted the build after modifying the json file.